# Is it possible to get only Super administrators from GApps(all domains) under reseller,using reseller account

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-workspace

I have a list of domains of all my gapps customers.I want to get only users who have super admin privilege for all those domains.I can fetch all users for the domain and iterate over them and filter out only supers admins. But it will be a lot of api calls.

There has to be another way....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both information list of all domains and list of users under a domain are not possible is one API Call. You have to make a list of domains call then make each call for a domain and get the list of users as you have mentioned been doing. However, you can avoid getting all users and get only admin users instead. There is a parameter in [API call](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) as `query` where you can mention `isAdmin=true` to get only super Admins.

But Google provides [batch request](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch) to combine multiple API calls in one request which you can readily use to fulfill your purpose.

Comment: The`query` parameter probably saved me few hundred api calls.Thanks